# componentDidUpdate keeps getting called

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
 componentDidUpdate () {
        this.showPosts();   
  }

showPosts = async () => {

    var userID = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userID');

    fetch(strings.baseUri+"getPostWithUserID", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
           Accept: 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
            "user_id": userID
        })
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {

        let jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseJson));

        if (jsonObj.status=="true") {

            this.setState({ 
                data: responseJson.data, 
                imageSrc: responseJson.data.imgSrc,
            });    
        } 
        else {       
                this.setState({show: false});
        }  

        })      
  }
```

I'm calling showPosts function from componentDidUpdate to show my updated Flatlist. But componentDidUpdate keeps getting called. Should I use  shouldComponentUpdate ?

========================== UPDATED CODE ============================

This is from **Home Screen**

```
 async componentDidMount () {
        this._isMounted = true;
        await this.showPosts();
  }

componentDidUpdate () {
     this.showPosts();   
}



 showPosts = async () => {

try {    
var userID = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userID');

fetch(strings.baseUri+"getPostWithUserID", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
       Accept: 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 
        "user_id": userID
    })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {

    let jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseJson));

    if (jsonObj.status=="true") {

        this.setState({ 
            data: responseJson.data, 
            imageSrc: responseJson.data.imgSrc, 
        });

    } 
    else {
        if (this._isMounted) {
            this.setState({show: false});
        }
    }  

    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }

  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }
```

This is **Image Descrpiption** screen from where I'll navigate back to Home Screen

```
    postData = async () => {

    this.setState({loading: true});

    var location = await AsyncStorage.getItem('location');
    var path = await AsyncStorage.getItem('path');
    var post_type = await AsyncStorage.getItem('post_type');
    var userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userID');

    var newPath = path.split("/");
    var imageName = newPath[newPath.length-1];

    const formData = new FormData();

    var media = {
        uri: path,
        name: imageName,
        type: 'image/jpg',
    };

    formData.append('image', media);
    formData.append('user', userId);
    formData.append('description',this.state.description);
    formData.append('location',"usa");
    formData.append('post_type',post_type);
    formData.append('userprofile_picture',imageName);


    fetch(strings.baseUri+"addPosts",{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
        body: formData,
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

         let jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseJson));

         if (jsonObj.status=="true") {  

            this.props.navigation.popToTop() 
            && this.props.navigation.navigate('Home'); // This navigates me to the HomeScreen

         } 
         else {

         } 
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
      });

  }
```

Answer (score 3):

**ComponentDidUpdate** is an update **LifeCycle Hook**, this will get triggered when there is something is changed in the component **State** or **Props**.

**Coming to your code:** 
You are calling a handler **showPosts**  to **setState**, that will again trigger the update lifecycle.

This will lead to an infinite loop.

> Solution

1. If you want to load the posts only in the first time, then move to **Creational** Life Cycle hook ( **componentDidMount** ).

   ```
   componentDidMount() { // This just gets called once in creational lifecycle //
       this.showPosts();  }
   ```
2. if you want this to always have the latest data, then there are two ways

   - **Updating component is in the same component tree branch:**, In this case , it's easy to achieve this you can pass the **state** from the updating component down to child component has props, your job is done OR if they are siblings then do a **level up** you can move the state one level up and have it coming in has props.
   - **Updating component is in the different component tree branch:** I recommend using [REDUX](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react), this is the main use of redux.

**shouldComponentUpdate** Yes definitely you can use this to verify the data and the load if needed, but be careful by using this your components update depends on the code in this.

Please check https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: Praveen can you please give me a small demo code on how I can implement that in my case?

Comment: @shubhamBhist I have updated my answer, please try moving to componentDidMount ( if you want to load the data initially only )

Comment: Praveen I want to call showPosts everytime my data is being updated. Is your way the right way in that case?

Comment: from where does this data change? I mean from which component does is change? is that component in the same component tree branch ?

Comment: It's from a different screen. Different component

Comment: Can I not do it without Redux?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187174/discussion-between-praveen-rao-chavan-g-and-shubham-bisht).

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidUpdate()` is called when the state is changed (calling `setState()`) and if you do it inside the showPosts that is also inside the `componentDidUpdate()` you are creating an infinite state updating.

Comment: then what should I be doing?

Comment: Add an if condition to check if you already have shown the posts so you avoid calling again the method. Or use the componentDidMount cycle method

Comment: If you want to update the posts every time another variable changes (like userId) then I would use a variable called shouldUpdatePosts and set it to true when that variable changes, otherwise to false.

Comment: But in my case, if I use `componentDidUpdate () {
      if(this.state.data != null)
        this.showPosts();   
  }` then it'll still keep calling because I want my list to be updated everytime home screen is loaded

Comment: Ok then you need a variable that changes when you switch between screens and based on that you load the posts.

Comment: Wouldn't the `componentDidUpdate` keep updating anyway?

Comment: Equally I recommend you to take a look into Epics using Redux state management. Is the proper way to do that stuff: https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call this in that way if you do in `ComponentDidUpdate` and update state in the method call by `ComponentDidUpdate` then a infinite loop start.

```
componentDidMount () {
        this.showPosts();   
  }
```

================EDITED=======================

If you want to use only `ComponentDidUpdate` then you can use it like.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
// only update if not match I don't know what's your data is so add a 
// simple check like we use for strings.
  if (prevState.data !== this.state.data) {
    this.showPosts();
  }
}
```

Just use `prevState` to match.

Comment: Yes, so what should I do?

Comment: You just replace your ComponentDidUpdate method to 
```componentDidMount () {
        this.showPosts();   
  }```

Comment: but I want my data to be updated every time this screen gets called

Comment: My requirement - I have a home screen. And below is a tab called AddPost on which I click and there opens a new screen, where I capture an image and send that image to my api. As soon as the image is sent to api, my screen navigates back to Home Screen and I want that last picture click to be shown on Homescreen

Comment: Check my edited answer if you fill any difficulty then let me know.

Comment: No. With your answer, it isn't doing anything.

Comment: Please let me know current behavior if you are not getting same result the what's the issue now.

Comment: With the if condition you recommended me, the data is not updating anymore

Comment: Please print `console.log("prevState.data" , prevState.data);` and `console.log("this.state.data" , this.state.data);` and share result with me.

Comment: Please print before if condition in `componentDidUpdate` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this too

> Common parent component

Create a new component say **Posts**.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HomeScreen from '../../HomeScreen';
import ImageDescription from '../../ImageDescription';

class Posts extends Component {

    constructor(){
     super();
     this.state = {
       dataEditted: false;
     }
    }

    newDataHandler = () =>{
      this.setState({dataEditted:true}); // this is flag to identify that there is change in data //
    }

    resetnewDataHandler = () =>{
      this.setState({dataEditted:false}); // this handler is used to reset the falg back to initial //
    }

    render () {
        const homeScreen =  <HomeScreen editted={this.state.editted} resetHandler={this.resetnewDataHandler}/>;
        const imageDescription = <ImageDescription newdataHandler={this.resetnewDataHandler}/>

        return (
            <div>
            {homeScreen}
            {imageDescription}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Posts;
```

This component is going to serve as a bridge to move data between.

Whenever there is fresh data in **ImageDescription** Component use the `newDataHandler` passed has `props` to update the common parent, then the **dataEditted** will be updated and passed has props to **homeScreen Component**, now in this `componentDidUpdate` of **homeScreen** check whether its true, then call `this.showPosts()` and also call `resetnewDataHandler`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this code helped me. `componentDidMount () {
            this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
                this.showPosts();
           });
    }`

Comment: @shubhamBisht sure

Comment: Can you please check our chat room too. I've sent you a text there

Comment: can you please show me a small example of how to use `componentDidUpdate` with it's default parameters `prevProps, prevState`. TIA :)